# Set vwashape hyperlink programmatically

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, visio

Is it possible to programmatically set the hyperlink of a vwashape in Javascript?
I know there is a get method to get the links(vwashape.getHyperlinks()) but is there a set method or do I need to upload the visio file to visio, change  the links and reupload it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after some struggling I found a solution.

Because I didnt found a way to set the hyperlinks on the object. I used the vwacontroll.addhandler onselected to bypass the problem.

```
vwaControl.addHandler("shapeselectionchanged", onShapeSelectionChanged);
...


onShapeSelectionChanged = function(source, args) {

    try {

        var shape = vwaShapes.getItemById(args);

        var linkArr = shape.getHyperlinks();

        for (var i = 0; i < linkArr.length; i++) {
            var linkUrl = linkArr[i].value;

            //manipulate link
            linkUrl = linkUrl.replace("origintext", "new text");
            window.location.href = linkUrl;
        }
    } catch(ex) {
        console.log("onselected " + ex);
    }

};
```